# Returning only the vertices in the actual shortest path

Tags: java, shortest-path, breadth-first-search, graph-traversal

I know the title is a bit messy, but I don't know how to explain it better.

**What I'm trying to do:**

Using a graph found in a text file, find and print the shortest path (minimum amount of vertices) from vertex A to vertex B.

Note: using breadth-first search, not Dijkstra's.

**What I've got:**

A working algorithm that applies BFS on the graph, but no good way of actually printing out the shortest path.

I'm having a hard time **distinguishing a vertex in the shortest path from one that is simply run through the algorithm, but not in the shortest path.**

For example: Find the shortest path between 0 and 4.
0 connects to 1,2 and 3. 1 connects to 4.
My path turns out to be [0,1,2,3,4] instead of [0,1,4].

I haven't been able to find any threads asking the same question, or any walk-through of BFS that includes this, so I'm not sure if I'm making this out to be *way* harder than it is?

**Edit:** code for those who may be interested (not sure at all if I'm avoiding circles?)

**Edit 2:** Changed the way I store my path to a Stack.

```
public String findPath(int v, int w) {
    Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[g.numVertices()];

    q.add(v);
    Stack<Integer> path = new Stack<Integer>();
    while(q.peek() != null) {
        runBFS(q.poll(),w,visited,q,path);
    }
    return path.toString();
} 

private void runBFS(int v, int w, boolean[] visited, Queue<Integer> q, Stack<Integer> path) {
    if(visited[v]) {
    }
    else if(v == w) {
        path.add(v);
        q.clear();
    }
    else {
        path.add(v);
        visited[v] = true;
        VertexIterator vi = g.adjacentVertices(v);
        while(vi.hasNext()) {
                q.add(vi.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Some explanation of variables and methods:

v = vertex of origin

w = target vertex

g = graph

vi = a normal iterator that iterates over the neighbours of v

**Thanks for reading!**

Comment: Hi, could you post a source code.

Comment: How is your graph represented in your code? How do you avoid circles? There are quite a few questions like this that would be best answered by you posting some of your code...

Comment: I've added some code. If there is any missing info about the graph let me know.

Comment: I think I am missing a few things here. For one, aren't `String` objects in Java immutable? What good does changing `path` in `runBFS` do?

Comment: You're absolutely right, my bad. I have however changed it from String to Stack now and will make the appropriate changes in the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will have to have specific path field for each vertex. That way you can keep track of the paths you've chosen, hence the short path found. I will use an String array, just like you used the Boolean array for storing visited vertices.

```
public String findPath(int v, int w) {
    Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[g.numVertices()];
    String[] pathTo = new String[g.numVertices()];

    q.add(v);
    pathTo[v] = v+" ";
    while(q.peek() != null) {
        if(runBFS(q.poll(),w,visited,q,pathTo))
        break;
    }
    return pathTo[w];
}

private boolean runBFS(int v, int w, boolean[] visited, Queue<Integer> q, String[] pathTo) {
    if(visited[v]) {
    }
    else if(v == w)
        return true; 
    }
    else {
        visited[v] = true;
        VertexIterator vi = g.adjacentVertices(v);
        while(vi.hasNext()) {
            int nextVertex = vi.next();
            pathTo[nextVertex] = pathTo[v] + nextVertex + " ";
            q.add(nextVertex);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks a lot!
Great solution, I think my problem was that I was only interested in the path from X to Y, and nothing else.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Another compact (space-wise) solution that us assistants have suggested and doesn't use O(n^2) storage space is to have each node store only which node it came from. This can be done by changing the visited-list to an integer array (`int[] visited`).

step 1: initialize visited list, so that every element is `'-1'`, or "unvisited"

step 2: mark the first node as visited by itself `visited[v] = v;`

Do a BFS (like you do, with the following modifications:)

when moving from v -> v_next:

```
if(visited[v_next] == -1)
{
  visited[v_next] = v;
  q.put(v_next);
}
// else skip it, it's already been visited
```

This way, if w is reachable, visited[w] will store which node it came from, from that node, you can backtrack all the way back to v and finally print them in the opposite order. (This is done either using a stack or a recursive print method.)

Hope that makes sense. :)

Answer (score 3):

When you store a vertex in the BFS queue, you also need to store *a copy of the path through which it has been reached*, so that it will be available once that vertex is dequeued. As it is now, your code does not keep any kind of path information on the queued vertices - it only keeps a list of the nodes it visits.

You could, for example, use a separate queue that will be processed in parallel, in which you will store the current path, and then restore it once you dequeue the next vertex to search.

Comment: This helpful explanation was very helpful. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48260217/3992939) my implementation

Answer (score 1):

You need to push your current node onto a stack, and only print the whole stack out once you reach the destination.

Comment: This returned the exact same result as my previous method, could you please be a little bit more elaborate?

Comment: Were you popping it back off when you backed up?